# How to import data quickly

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I have json data from using model derivative API.Using below link,

[https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/]

This data taking more time to import into database.

Please help me to import data quickly into database.

Thank you.

Comment: This question probably has more to do with the database that you are trying to import into, and next to nothing to do with the Forge API. What database are you talking about, please?

Comment: I am getting metadata from the API, I need to save all the metadata into SQL database. This data count is more than 50 thousand. How to import this data quickly without taking more time

Answer (score 1):

This question is related to your SQL database and its import facilities and has nothing whatsoever to do with the Autodesk Forge API.